# Qt Creator for Mac

Tags: data-transfer, software, ide

My Uni course requires me to use Qt Creator for our coursework but I would like to also put it on my Mac so that I can do more work at home. I had assumed it was available for free but when I tried to download it, I was told to register for a 30-day trial, which I took to mean that the software isn't free.

Can I get Qt Creator for Mac for free and where from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to the Qt open-source site:
http://qt-project.org/downloads

> The Qt SDK version 1.2.1 released on April 11th contains:
>
> - Qt libraries version 4.8.1
> - Simulator for Symbian phones and the Nokia N9
> - **Qt Creator IDE version 2.4.1**
> - Qt Mobility version 1.2
> - Qt development tools
> - Remote compilers

The Qt SDK includes Qt Creator.

---

Note that the installer is **760 MB**.

Comment: Thank you. I am also a little unsure about the usage of Qt: can I make GUI apps for any platform? I seem to be seeing Nokia a lot when I search for Qt, what has Nokia got to do with it?

Comment: @Sam - The idea behind Qt is you can generally compile your app for any platform. Realistically, you generally have to do a bit of tweaking for each platform, but it does make it easier then writing native apps for every platform.

Comment: You're seeing nokia because nokia owns the Qt trademarks, and is largely the driving force behind it's development.